how to Identify SendGrid webhook for multiple event webhook implementation?
I am currently working on an post API endpoint where i will receive data from SendGrid Event Webhooks. The issue I am currently having is identifying which specific webhook that is sending data, so that i can use correct corresponding public key for signature verification.
I saw information regarding adding custom data into headers, but all i can find in that regard is while sending the email and getting a response directly after, while I want to have either custom data or the Webhook id in the Event webhook data i receive in my post endpoint.
Anyone have a good idea of how to identify which Event Webhook is sending the specific webhook data?
I have been using mainly https://webhook.site/ to look at the data that is sent with SendGrid event webhooks. Currently i have not found a way to get some information to identify which specific webhook is sending data to know which public key is applicable.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sendgrid/api-reference/webhooks/get-an-event-webhook#responses - the response contains an id (automatically generated and not changeable, but if you only need to configure your signature keys once, probably not too much of a drawback), and it also contains friendly_name, which you can configure yourself.

I did try with friendly name. But i could not see either the friendly name or webhook id in the header or body of message

I use a variable in the url the webhook posts to. I'm only sending one event though. I wanted to identify which account it's coming from.
https://example.com/webhook.asp?sgwhid=12345

